# Python capitalize list of lists of strings

Tags: python, list, capitalization

I am trying to capitalize each string in a list in python 3. I am using this code

```
def capitalize_nested(t):
    res=[]
    for s in t:
        if isinstance(s,list):
            capitalize_nested(s)
        res.append(s.capitalize())
    return res
```

The code works for a list of strings, but not for a list of lists of strings, e.g. when I run it for t=["asd",["asd"]] I would expect ["Asd",["Asd"]] as output, instead I obtain the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                             
  File "/home/main.py", line 10, in <module>                                                                                   
    print(capitalize_nested(t))                                                                                                
  File "/home/main.py", line 6, in capitalize_nested                                                                           
    res.append(s.capitalize())                                                                                                 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'capitalize'
```

I don't get what the error means. Why does the code treat the elements of the sublist in the recursion as lists instead of strings?

Comment: Show input and expected output data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is already telling you the problem: you're trying to call `capitalize` on a list, which is not possible.

The reason for this: if `s` is a list, you are calling your function recursively, which is just fine. But after the recursive call returns, you are calling `res.append(s.capitalize())`, which gives you the error, because `s` is a list and therefore there is no `capitalize()` function.

Better do something like this:

```
def capitalize_nested(t):
    res=[]
    for s in t:
        if isinstance(s, list):
            to_append = capitalize_nested(s)
        else:
            to_append = s.capitalize()
        res.append(to_append)
    return res
```

Example:

Input: `["asd",["asd"]]`

Outputs: `['Asd', ['Asd']]`

Note: Of course, this is not the most elegant or beautiful solution, but I didn't want to change your code too much and it hopefully explains the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're directly calling `capitalize_nested` instead of appending `capitalize_nested` in one branch of your code.  Try this:

```
def capitalize_nested(t):
    res=[]
    for s in t:
        if isinstance(s,list):
            res.append(capitalize_nested(s))
        else:
            res.append(s.capitalize())
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code if the type of `s` is a list then after executing the inside of the if statment the compiler also will invoke the `capitalize` method (which is not defined for the list `s`). So You need an else statment. Also you have to append the result of the recurrence:

```
def capitalize_nested(t):
    res=[]
    for s in t:
        if type(s) == list:
            res.append(capitalize_nested(s))
        else:
            res.append(s.capitalize())
    return res


print capitalize_nested(['asd', ['asd',]])
```

This should output:

```
['Asd', ['Asd']]
```